# org.apache.commons.net.ssh documentation

Tags: java, ssh, apache-commons-net

It's weird! I searched for "org.apache.commons.net.ssh documentation", and there's nothing there. I mean there's not even an entry for ssh in http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/

however I found examples, having following import:

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ssh.SSHClient;
```

I need to executes some commands using `SSHClient` and get the output to parse, and I don't find any documentation in that regard.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

http://commons-net-ssh.googlecode.com/svn/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/net/ssh/SSHClient.java

checkout the ssh project and check the comments (could not find a better option)

https://code.google.com/p/commons-net-ssh/source/checkout

Comment: I checked your answer, thanks. still waiting for better references.